# How to create 1-100 in 10 rows?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, numbers, rows

I'm trying to get the following exercise:

> "Write a program containing a pair of neste while loops that displays the integer values 1-100, ten numbers per row, with the columns alignes as below.
>
> ```
>  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
> ```

So far I've come up with this:

```
lijst = list(range(1, 101))
i = 0

while i < 100:
    print(lijst[i],"\t", end=" ".format(">"))
    i = i+1
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print("")
```

Although it produces the things I need, the tabs aren't working. whenever I try to add spaces instead of a tab, things move way too much on the second and further rows. 
Furthermore I can't seem to find out why the `.format(">")` doesn't work. I've tried to apply `.format(">3")` but that didn't do anything at all.

Comment: I suggest you use the [_Format Specification Mini-Language_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to format strings that when printed will look like what you want (it gives you a lot of control). It is typically used via statements similar to `print('<format spec>'.format(<data items>))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `{:>5d}` format style to right align integers 5 spaces

```
lijst = list(range(1, 101))
i = 0

while i < 100:
    print("{:>5d}".format(lijst[i]), end=" ")
    i = i+1
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print("")
```

Output:

```
    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10 
   11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20 
   21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28    29    30 
   31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38    39    40 
   41    42    43    44    45    46    47    48    49    50 
   51    52    53    54    55    56    57    58    59    60 
   61    62    63    64    65    66    67    68    69    70 
   71    72    73    74    75    76    77    78    79    80 
   81    82    83    84    85    86    87    88    89    90 
   91    92    93    94    95    96    97    98    99   100
```

Comment: i think he was wanting `'{>5s}'.format(my_num)`  (It also looks like he wants to right align not left align)

Comment: Well, in strings I can right align the string in a certain amount of characters with the use of format(">20") (for example). That's why I though I could use it as well on integers. But unfortunately I can't. 
The output looks good, but how do I right align everything?

Comment: `'{>5s}'.format(my_num)`   , means right align my number to 5 spaces....

Comment: Great, thanks for helping! Solved the problem!